# Increase maximum number of iterations in lmrob

Tags: r, regression, robust

How do you increase the maximum number of iterations (i.e., the `maxit.scale` parameter) in the `lmrob` function in the `robustbase` package in R?

The default is 200, but I want to increase it.

Answer (score 2):

It might help if you said you were using the robustbase package.

`?lmrob` would bring up a help page, and reading it points to `lmrob.control` which looks like

```
lmrob.control(setting, seed = NULL, nResample = 500,
              tuning.chi = NULL, bb = 0.5, tuning.psi = NULL,
              max.it = 50, groups = 5, n.group = 400,
              k.fast.s = 1, best.r.s = 2,
              k.max = 200, maxit.scale = 200, k.m_s = 20,
              refine.tol = 1e-7, rel.tol = 1e-7, solve.tol = 1e-7,
              trace.lev = 0,
              mts = 1000, subsampling = c("nonsingular", "simple"),
              compute.rd = FALSE, method = "MM", psi = "bisquare",
              numpoints = 10, cov = NULL,
              split.type = c("f", "fi", "fii"), fast.s.large.n = 2000, ...)
```

with the detail

`k.fast.s` (for the fast-S algorithm): Number of local improvement steps (“I-steps”) for each re-sampling candidate.

`k.m_s` (for the M-S algorithm): specifies after how many unsucessful refinement steps the algorithm stops.

`best.r.s` (for the fast-S algorithm): Number of of best candidates to be iterated further (i.e., “refined”); is denoted t in Salibian-Barrera & Yohai(2006).

`k.max` (for the fast-S algorithm): maximal number of refinement steps for the “fully” iterated best candidates.

`maxit.scale` integer specifying the maximum number of C level `find_scale()` iterations.

so you presumably want to change one of these.

Answer (score 1):

```
library(robustbase)
data(starsCYG, package="robustbase")
a1<-lmrob.control()
RlmST<-lmrob(log.light~log.Te,data=starsCYG,control=a1)
```

Increase `maxit.scale`; it's not really clear from your question 
which one of the iteration counts breaks you want to increase, but I suppose 
it's `maxit.scale` since it's the only one that is set to 200 by default. Here I increase `maxit.scale` to 201:

```
a1$maxit.scale<-201
RlmST<-lmrob(log.light~log.Te,data=starsCYG,control=a1)
```

Anyway, you can change the other in pretty much the same way: check:

```
?lmrob.control
```